# How to automatically resize a Label node in Godot?

Tags: label, godot

I am having trouble with resizing a font inside a button in Godot. The idea is that, inside the button, we have 1:1:1 rect/label/rect proportion with text inside label as big as it can vertically be. I tried to synchronize the size of the Label rect with the font size, with the Resized() property, with no success yet.

The node tree is Button>VBoxContainer>(TextureRect, Label, TextureRect).

Before:

[image: Before]

After (no success):

[image: After]

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe try putting your buttons & etc  into a `CanvasLayer` and then try resizing and see if it works or not